# VS Code's file changes watcher stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

I have vsc version 1.63.2. I'm getting the following notification:

"File changes watcher stopped unexpectedly. A reload of the window may enable the watcher again unless the workspace cannot be watched for file changes."
[image: notification]

When I click the reload button, the issue is temporarily fixed and Source Control shows changes to my files. Git in CLI is working fine; `git log --raw` shows changes to my files correctly. I've tested brand new and old repositories and workspaces. The problem occurs in all of them. Any help troubleshooting this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into this issue today and found my solution by viewing the "Window" logs using the "Developer: Open Log File..." command from the Command Palette.

In my case, the problem was that I had added a folder to my workspace that I had since deleted on the file system. The log in question looked something like:

```
... [error] [File Watcher (parcel)] Unexpected error: Invalid handle (EUNKNOWN) (path: \path\that\no\longer\exists)
... [error] [File Watcher (parcel)] restarting watcher after error: Invalid handle
```

Hopefully viewing this log helps you find out what's breaking in your specific case.

Comment: Thanks for the lead- it helped a lot! My logs do show an error: `[File Watcher (parcel)] Unexpected error: Bad file descriptor (EUNKNOWN) (path: /home/username/my/file/path)` I haven't figured out the solution yet.

Comment: Hmm, I might try investigating the file ownership (root or other users, permissions, etc) or maybe if another program is playing with the files in the background. If you can identify a common pattern for what files/folders throw that error, you also might just end up ignoring them from the watcher using the `files.watcherExclude` setting. Best of luck!

Comment: Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70783895/15843133)

Answer (score 7):

I also encountered this problem. I was using VSCode and opening a folder in it on WSL Ubuntu 20.04. The solution for me was to install the **VS Code Remote - WSL** extension.

I hope this will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR** : on Windows 10, if you have Cygwin64 installed and you got a Git For Windows update, check Git for Windows path comes before Git from Cygwin path in environment variables.

**Long version** : Just got into the same error today. The Git Lens extension was not working anymore.
I'm on Win 10, so there is no way (at least I didn't find one) to increase the limit of watchers [like on linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc). My VS Code is v1.66.2, Git Lens extension is v12.0.6.
In my case, the logs said :

```
... [error] [File Watcher (parcel)] Unexpected error: Invalid handle (EUNKNOWN) (path: cygwin\g\path\that\exists)
```

Notice that ENOSPC !== EUNKNOWN

So I searched everywhere with little to no success, except here where [Gordon Christopher Weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875413/gordon-christopher-weeks)'s answer actually hinted me towards that logs.
Then I remembered several things :

- I have a terminal installed that's called cygwin64 and that allows me to use some linux utilities otherwise not available on Win (like rsync);
- two days ago, I authorized an update for Git for Windows (2.35.2);
- when I installed cygwin, the tutorial I followed told me about following a certain sequence in the Windows `path` environment variable

So I checked the `path` variable, noticed the Git update deleted the initial path to git and put it in the last place. I only had to move it up, before the cygwin64 path to git.exe (a git utility is included with cygwin) and everything's back to normal.

Hope this helps and so you won't waste the time I did !

Answer (score 0):

[Possible quick solution] First thing to check is to see if you are tracking a WSL folder in a Visual Studio Code Explorer workspace *AND* you switched VS Code back to windows (was in a WSL distro).

If so, then right-clicking on it and selecting "remove from workspace" will also remove it from the file change watcher.

Refresh the file change watcher (bell icon, lower right corner of window) to see if it cleans up the problem.

This was the issue I had with the system.