# How to fix bad file descriptor error in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have vsc version 1.63.2. I'm getting the following notification:"File changes watcher stopped unexpectedly. A reload of the window may enable the watcher again unless the workspace cannot be watched for file changes." In the "Window" logs (opened using the "Developer: Open Log File..." command from the Command Palette), there's an error:

```
[renderer4] [error] [File Watcher (parcel)] Unexpected error: Bad file descriptor (EUNKNOWN) (path: /home/username/project_root)
[renderer4] [error] [File Watcher (parcel)] gave up attempting to restart watcher after error: Bad file descriptor
```

Any help troubleshooting this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug when the project directory contains files you don't own.
For instance, you can have a docker volume that generate root files. -_-
A fix has been done but isn't released yet: http://giters.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139523

As a workaround you can find offending files with:
`find . ! -user myusername`

Then you should add them to settings.json:

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/*/**": true,
    "**/mongodb/mongo-volume/**": true,
    "**/rabbitmq/data/**": true,
    "**/rabbitmq/logs/**": true
},
```

You must provide full relative path from project root directory or it won't work.